# What Internet bandwidth speed tools are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, bandwidth

Is there any applications on Ubuntu that could measure your bandwidth/download speed?

I would like to start a few downloads and use a bandwidth monitor like application that will give me the total download and upload speed in Mbps.  There used to be a software like that for windows, I can't recall the name though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Netspeed monitor applet. At 1st, install it from software center, simple "netspeed monitor" will give you the result, install the package. Now if you are using GNOME, right click on panel, select add to panel and then select netspeed monitor. You can see the incoming and outgoing speed on the panel all time

Answer (score 7):

I use `nethogs`. Console program. Works great.

`sudo apt-get install nethogs`

[image: nethogz]

Comment: I wish i could vote many times over for this.

Answer (score 6):

[gkrellm](http://freshmeat.net/projects/gkrellm) and [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) are useful monitoring tools for gnome that will allow you to have a visual of your network bandwidth behavior. Both them are not limited to the monitoring the network activity. Screenshots here:

### [gkrellm](http://freshmeat.net/projects/gkrellm)

[image]

### [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

more conky's screenshots available at: http://conky.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html

Answer (score 4):

[speedtest.net](Http://speedtest.net) is awesome, no need for an app...

Comment: Yes. To measure your bandwidth reliably, you need a third party such as speedtest.net to measure against, not a local application.

Answer (score 3):

gnome-system-monitor Resources tab has a current network traffic graph as well as upload/download totals since last boot.

Answer (score 1):

**NetHogs- Create a Icon to run NetHogs in terminal**

In terminal run

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/NetHogs.desktop
```

Then add these lines in to that empty document

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=NetHogs
Comment=Network Monitor
Exec=sudo uxterm -e nethogs ppp0 %F
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/apps/utilities-system-monitor.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;System;
NoDisplay=false
```

Replace `ppp0` in `Exec=sudo uxterm -e nethogs ppp0` with `lo`,`wlan0` or `eth0` depending on your interface.

Save and close this file

Now open dash and search for NetHogs. You will have a fully functional Icon.

Answer (score 0):

Some other easily installable Software are:

**1.Knemo**

It is a Panel Icon

When click and select, this gives a ***Status Dialog*** as well as a ***Traffic Plotter***

```
sudo apt-get install knemo
```

[image]

**2. System Monitor**

It is a inbuilt tool in Ubuntu,

In the ***System Monitor*** tool, in ***Resources*** tab, there is a graph called ***Network History***

***Type "System Monitor" in Dash*

[image]

**3. System Load Indicator**

This is a Indicator in the Panel

When clicked on, it display data about CPU,Memory,Network

```
sudo apt-get install Indicator-multiload
```

In that Icon, there is a live graph about network.

[image]